Settle a debate on probability
I asked my friend a math problem the other day:
If you are taking a true or false test with 20 questions, you know the amount of trues in the test is normally distributed. The mean amount of trues is 10, with a standard deviation of one true answer. Eg. 68% of the time there are between 9 and 11 true answers. If you have answered all of the first 19 questions and you know you got them all correct, but on the last one you are not sure, but you are 80% confident the answer is true (with no consideration of the distribution). My question was: how many of the previous 19 questions would have to be true for you to go against this 80% and select false. Eg. if the last 19 questions were all true you may assume it's extremely unlikely for the last one to also be true.
I thought the answer to be 12 truths, as if you answer the final question true the distribution moves from 2 standard deviations from the mean to 3 standard deviations from the mean. The chance of this goes from 2.5% to 0.15%, this decrease is much less likely than the 20% you don't know how to do the question. So therefore at this point of 12 truths, you should go against your answer and choose false.
My friend however argued the question was similar to flipping 20 coins, and said the previous outcomes shouldn't affect future outcomes. Eg. even though you expect the 20 flips to be normally distributed if you get 19 heads in a row it doesn't affect the probability of the next flip.
I saw where he was coming from but thought maybe this question was different as someone (a teacher perhaps) would've chosen the answers ahead of time and the past question answers may affect the future questions' answers.
Wondering who's correct here? Or if the question is somehow ambiguous?

This question belongs on CrossValidated.SE.

The teacher has a set of questions (30 questions, 100 questions, 1000000 questions ? We don't know), they are normally distributed etc etc ... He selects 20 questions randomly.  If the full set contains 1000000 questions, the comparaison with flipping coins is correct. If the full set is 30 questions, it is not.

"you know the amount of trues in the test is normally distributed" What does that mean? The normal distribution is a continuous distribution, but the amount of trues can only be a natural number.

By "normally distributed", do you just mean "binomially distributed"?  for a finite system like this, that would make a lot more sense.  Otherwise, do you really mean to aggregate the tails into the end cases?  Though of course the binomial doesn't fit the standard deviation.

Regardless of that, this should be addressed via Bayes' Theorem.  You are certainly correct that the distribution has an impact on your revised estimate of the probability.

The abbreviation is spelled "e.g.", not "eg.", and it means "for example." In the context where you wrote "Eg.", "i.e." ("that is") would have been more appropriate. Also, either abbreviation should be followed by a comma. But I recommend against using either e.g. or i.e. at all except in the rare circumstances where both you and your expected audience have complete knowledge of the meanings and usage of these ancient Latin abbreviations. Use English words instead.

"you know the amount of trues in the test is normally distributed" - is this meant to be an assumption or a deduction? From just knowing you are presented with a quiz it is far from obvious that the answers are random at all, and if so what their distribution is. It sounds like you are trying to estimate the distribution given partial information - is that what you're trying to do? Frankly it seems like you are both imagining different schemes for randomly assigning questions, which will lead to different answers.

Of course the distribution of "Trues" matter.  Consider an extreme case where you guarantee in advance that there are exactly $12$ Trues.  In that case, the final answer is determined, regardless of your view on the question.
To your specific question:
It's not clear what you mean by "normally distributed" so let's assume that you mean to simply discretize that.  That is, we declare that the probability that there are exactly $n$ Trues, $p_n$, is given by the normal probability that a random draw lies between $n-.5$ and $n+.5$.  Other guesses are possible, but this seems to fit your intent.
With this choice we get, (ignoring the low probability cases):
$$p_6=.00023\quad p_7=.00598\quad p_8=.0606\quad p_9=.24173\quad p_{10}=.38292$$ $$p_{11}=.24173\quad p_{12}=.0606\quad p_{13}=.00598\quad p_{14}=.00023$$
Now, suppose there were exactly $n$ Trues in the first $19$ questions. There are two ways to explain your answer of True for the $20^{th}$.  Either you are correct ($.8$ chance) and there were $n+1$ Trues in total ($p_{n+1}$) or you were wrong ($.2$) and there were $n$ Trues in total ($p_n$).  By Bayes, the probability of the former case is $$\psi_n=\frac {.8\times p_{n+1}}{.8\times p_{n+1}+.2\times p_n}$$
These values are easily computed and we see that $\psi_{12}$ is the first of them which is $<.5$, it is $.28291$.  Thus, if you are going strictly by the probabilities, that's the level at which you would flip your vote.

A simple argument is that if your friend is correct (that is, if each answer is really independent in probability from the other answers), the distribution of the number of true answers on the test would be a binomial distribution.
The only binomial distribution that has support from $0$ to $20$ and has mean $10$ is the binomial distribution with $n=20$ and $p=1/2$. But the standard deviation of that distribution is $\sqrt5$, which is quite a bit larger than $1$.
Therefore the distribution of true answers on the test is not binomial and your friend's argument does not apply.

Addendum:
As pointed out in a comment, what I wrote above does not address a serious flaw in the question, which is that the number of correct true responses on the test cannot be normally distributed. You need a discrete distribution over the integers from $0$ to $20$ inclusive. You hint that this distribution should be approximately normal, but you don't say how, so the choice of approximation is ambiguous. We cannot give a precise answer to your original problem without choosing a discrete distribution; but I have taken your word that whatever the actual distribution is, its standard deviation is $1$.
So the original problem statement is ambiguous, but the question about your friend's argument is not.

I can't make sense of this. The OP seems to ask "the questions are normally distributed. are they binomially distributed?" and you answer "they aren't binomially distributed because the variance is wrong". Why not just say "they aren't binomially distributed because they're normally distributed" and stop there? Frankly I think the question doesn't make sense in its current form - but you answer as if it does.

@preferred_anon It is indeed unclear what OP means by the questions being normally distributed, because the normal distribution is altogether the wrong kind of distribution for an integer from $0$ to $20$. I consider therefore that the distribution is not really normal. Therefore simply saying "they aren't binomially distributed because they're normally distributed" would be wrong, because the number of true questions can't be normally distributed. OP may have in mind some approximation to the normal. I don't know which. But the standard deviation is unambiguous.
